# Networksimulation with memorystream

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream

I have to simulate a Network with nodes and the `MemoryStream`, I want to send objects messages from one node to another.

The problem is I always get exception when I want to dezerialize the `IMessage` object in the stream. Also, how I can simulate the `server.AcceptClient`?

Exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "The input stream does not have a valid binary format. The start contents (in bytes) are: 05-01-00-00-00-22-50-65-65-72-5F-74-6F -5F-50-65-65 ... "

Code:

```
public class Network
{
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public Network()
    {
        Nodes = new List<Node>();
    }

    public MemoryStream GetClientStream(string ip)
    {
        foreach (var item in Nodes)
        {
            if (item.Ip == ip)
            {
                return item.Stream;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}


public class Node
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }

    public Client ChordClient { get; set; }

    public MemoryStream Stream { get; set; }

    public Network ChordChain { get; set; }

    public Node(string ip, string peerOne, Network network)
    {
        ChordChain = network;
        Ip = ip;
        Console.WriteLine($"Peer with Port {ip} is listening");
        Task.Run(() => openServer());
    }

    private void openServer()
    {
        try
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

            Stream = new MemoryStream();
            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                int i;

                while ((i = Stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    Stream.Position = 0;
                    IMessage msg = NodeTest.DeserializeFromStream(Stream);

                    msg.DoOperate();

                    Stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
        }
    }

    public void Connect(String ip)
    {
        try
        {
            IMessage msg = new Message();

            MemoryStream stream = ChordChain.GetClientStream(ip);

            NodeTest.SerializeToStream(stream, msg);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", "sd");
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }

}

public class NodeTest
{

    public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(MemoryStream stream, object o)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);

        return stream;
    }

    public static IMessage DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {

        stream.Position = 0;
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        return (IMessage)(o);
    }
}

public class Message : IMessage
{

    public void DoOperate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

public interface IMessage
{
    void DoOperate();
}
```

Thanks for you help but now i have the problem how i can send the fix size of the object thaqt it works correctly

```
public class Node
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }

    public Client ChordClient { get; set; }

    public MemoryStream Stream { get; set; }

    public Network ChordChain {get; set; }

    public Node(string ip, string peerOne, Network network)
    {
        ChordChain = network;
        Ip = ip;
        Console.WriteLine($"Peer with Port {ip} is listening");
        Task.Run(() => openServer());
    }

    private void openServer()
    {
        try
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream(Ip);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            int i;

            while (true)
            {
                server.WaitForConnection();

                while ((i = server.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {

                    //Stream.Position = 0;
                    IMessage msg = NodeTest.DeserializeFromStream(server);

                    msg.DoOperate();
                }

            }

            //MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream(server);
            //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);

            //Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

            //Stream = new MemoryStream();
            //// Enter the listening loop.
            //while (true)
            //{
            //    int i;

            //    while ((i = Stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            //    {
            //        //Stream.Position = 0;
            //        IMessage msg = NodeTest.DeserializeFromStream(Stream);

            //        msg.DoOperate();

            //        Stream.Flush();
            //    }               
            //}
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
        }
    }

    public void Connect(String ip)
    {
        try
        {              
            IMessage msg = new Message();


            NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(ip);
            client.Connect();

            NodeTest.SerializeToStream(client, msg);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", "sd");

            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }  
    }

}

public class NodeTest
{

    public static void SerializeToStream(NamedPipeClientStream stream, object o)
    { 
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    }

    public static IMessage DeserializeFromStream(NamedPipeServerStream   stream)
    {

        //stream.Position = 0;
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        return (IMessage)(o);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of MemoryStream isn't thread safe. You can't reposition and read the stream on one thread while another is writing to it. To model this type of asynchronous communication, use pipe streams:

```
 NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe");
 server.WaitForConnection();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);

 [...]

 NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream("MyPipe");
 client.Connect();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but now i have the problem with the size of the object and i don't know how i can send the size of object with this one

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what is wrong with this, but you certainly have a problem knowing if you have the whole message or not.

If you send messages with serialization like this, then it is hard for each party to know if it recieved the whole message or not. The way to resolve this is to frame the serialized message, so for example you send:

```
...
[size][serialized message]
[size][serialized message]
...
```

So to send you (1) serialize to memory (2) get the size as how many bytes (3) write the size (4) write that many bytes

And to receive you (1) read the size (2) read exactly that many bytes into memory (3) deserialize

I would sort this out first.